# Turning a query into an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to turn results from a query into an array.

turn this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER");
```

into

```
$result = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'bob');
```

But I don't want `print_r()`, i want to echo php executable code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$records = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER ");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $records[] = $result;
}
```

Now you can use `$records` as your (re-usable) array.

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: note that `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will return only one row, you have to keep it in a loop to get all of them

Comment: I meant for unlimited records. But $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); will only work for that run, im trying to get an array i can run elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDO and [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll(); // get all rows
var_dump($results);

//to get only first row:
$result = $results[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]); //or echo
}
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score -1):

easy:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WHATEVER ");
if($result)
{
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
/*
manipule $result according you need
*/
print_r($result);
}
else{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Not so easy it seems. OP specifically said he didn't want `print_r()` but PHP executable code.

Comment: thaks, i don´t know this function